# Recommendations for a haemocytometer (phase-contrast)

Tags: microbiology, microscopy, visualization

I'm looking for recommendations for a haemocytometer that can be used with a phase-contrast microscope. I want to use it to quantify the vegetative and spore fraction in my samples. Can I use any haemocytometer, or should the counting chamber be reduced in overall thickness?